# How could I hide the Street Address whole div block and only show the Company block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not able to change the parent div tag names (div class="pc_flex_form_line_container")

```
 <div class="pc_flex_form_line_container">
       <div class="pc_flex_form_label_item">Company
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_required_flag_item"><img src="/corestrengths/s.gif" class="requiredFieldMarker" />
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_field_item"><input id="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingcompany" type="text" name="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingcompany" class="pc_medium_input_field" /> 
       </div>
   </div>



   <div class="pc_flex_form_line_container">
       <div class="pc_flex_form_label_item">Street Address
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_required_flag_item"><img src="/corestrengths/s.gif" class="requiredFieldMarker" />
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_field_item"><input id="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingstreet" type="text" name="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingstreet" class="pc_long_input_field" />
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `$('.pc_flex_form_line_container:eq(1)').hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by **the Street Address whole div block** you mean the second element with the class`pc_flex_form_line_container`. You can do it like this:

```js
$('.pc_flex_form_line_container:eq(1)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pc_flex_form_line_container">
       <div class="pc_flex_form_label_item">Company
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_required_flag_item"><img src="/corestrengths/s.gif" class="requiredFieldMarker" />
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_field_item"><input id="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingcompany" type="text" name="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingcompany" class="pc_medium_input_field" /> 
       </div>
   </div>



   <div class="pc_flex_form_line_container">
       <div class="pc_flex_form_label_item">Street Address
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_required_flag_item"><img src="/corestrengths/s.gif" class="requiredFieldMarker" />
       </div>
       <div class="pc_flex_form_field_item"><input id="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingstreet" type="text" name="siteQuickEventRegPage:SiteTemplate:evtRegForm:attendeeInfoForms:2:mailingstreet" class="pc_long_input_field" />
       </div>
   </div>
```